# How to correctly store settings / options

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a JS library (packaged with webpack) for my front end applications.

This library is simple but it needs to be configured :

src/index.js :

```
export const init = (options) => {
...
}
```

This library has a bunch of services that rely on the passed options :

src/services/index.js :

```
export const checkPerson = (person) => {
    // I have to use the "options" (passed in the "init")
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to store the options populated by the developers so that I can use those options in my other services?

Is it possible to store those options with JavaScript without storing in the session storage?

What is the best practice?

Comment: @CertainPerformance : thank you for your answer. Can you point to a repo or show us some code please ?

Comment: I used that pattern for for https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/Hide-Roomba-Bound-Posts/src/watchForClicksOnTables/settingsStore.ts, though it's basically just the same code as in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do in this situation is I have a dedicated module for storing and retrieving settings:

```
// src/settings.js
let settings;
export const setSettings = (newSettings) => {
  settings = newSettings;
};
export const getSettings = () => settings;
```

```
// src/index.js
import { setSettings } from './settings';
export const init = (options) => {
  setSettings(options);
  // ...
};
```

```
// src/services/index.js
import { getSettings } from '../settings';
export const checkPerson = (person) => {
  const settings = getSettings();
  // use settings
};
```

Whenever a module needs to know what the settings are, just import `getSettings` and call it. It's pretty easy to manage, and doesn't require storage anywhere outside the closure of the bundled script.